# Undefined function or variable "kernel_type"

Tags: matlab

I am just giving part of the MATLAB code that gives me a headaches.

```
function [hm,sm] = SKSClab(filename,data_type,maxk,true_labels,plot_flag)

%Inputs:

% filename: .txt file (or .jpg for images) with the data (instances as rows, features as columns)
% data_type: 
% 1) net_unw = unweighted network (filename represents the adjacency list)
% 2) net_w = weighted network (filename represents the adjacency list)
% 3) vector = generic data points
% 4) ts = time-series
% 5) img = image
% maxk: maximum number of clusters to look for
% true_labels: labels if present 
% plot_flag: 1 -> plot results, 0-> do not plot anything
```

Then

```
switch data_type
       case 'vector'
       THR_dim = 100;
       if(size(X,2)<THR_dim)
           kernel_type = 'RBF_kernel'; 
       else
           kernel_type = 'cosine_kernel'; %use cosine kernel when enough features are present
       end
       case 'ts'
       kernel_type = 'corrrbf_kernel';
       case 'net_w'
       kernel_type = 'cosine_kernel';
       case 'net_unw'
       kernel_type = 'cosine_kernel';
       case 'img'
       kernel_type = 'chisquared_kernel';
end

%Tuning
tunestruct = {samplefunc,numreps,data_type,MS_criterion};
[Xtrain,optk,optsig2,tuningExtras] = tuneSKSC(data,kernel_type,maxk,tunestruct);
```

When I invoke code like this

```
SKSClab('proba',3,6,1)
```

I got

```
Loading data...
Undefined function or variable "kernel_type".

Error in SKSClab (line 179)
[Xtrain,optk,optsig2,tuningExtras] = tuneSKSC(data,kernel_type,maxk,tunestruct);
```

There is also other function defined like this

```
 function [Xtrain,optk,optsig2,extras] = tuneSKSC(datastruct,kernel,maxk,tunestruct)
```

What is the problem?Should I define `kernel_type`?I do not have too much experiance with MATLAB.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that `kernel_type` will be defined only if the `data_type` argument is one of the strings `'vector'`, `'ts'`, `'new_w'`, `'new_unw'` and `'img'`. But you pass the argument `3` that doesn't match any of these cases, so `kernel_type` goes undefined, because there is no assignation to it.

To fix this add to the `switch` statement an `otherwise` branch:

```
    switch data_type
    case 'vector'
            THR_dim = 100;
            if(size(X,2)<THR_dim)
                    kernel_type = 'RBF_kernel'; 
            else
                    kernel_type = 'cosine_kernel';
            end
    case 'ts'
            kernel_type = 'corrrbf_kernel';
    case 'net_w'
            kernel_type = 'cosine_kernel';
    case 'net_unw'
            kernel_type = 'cosine_kernel';
    case 'img'
            kernel_type = 'chisquared_kernel';
    otherwise
            kernel_type = 'some_default_kernel_that_makes_sense';
    end;
```

The alternative is to pass the correct arguments:

```
SKSClab('proba','vector',6,1)
```

Comment: No,proba.txt is filename,3 is argument for vectors.

Comment: @MPejic Okay, I'll correct the answer. But still the problem is that you don't give the expected parameters to the function. the function really expects one of those strings in the second argument, and you give it a number/

Comment: @How should the parameters look like?

Comment: YOu can download code from http://www.esat.kuleuven.be/sista/ADB/langone/softwareSKSClab.php

Comment: @MPejic Thanks, but I don't need to :-) Please read the completed answer. The idea is to call correctly the function: `SKSClab('proba','vector',6,1)`

Comment: Works fine now,I see where was my mistake!

Answer (score 0):

I think it can have one of two causes: 
1) There is already a function in matlab that is named kernel_type
2) You didn't define kernel_type and you should just type kerneltype = ""; to declare an empty string

Comment: Yeah, I noticed my mistake, sorry!